# Calculating conditional probability of discrete uniform r.v.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, actuarial-science

X is a discrete uniform random variable on $\{a, a+1, a+2, ... , b\}$ with mean 7 and variance 4.

Find $Pr[X \leq 6| X > 4]$

I'm not familiar with the discrete uniform distribution. I was tempted to do the following:

$$Pr[X \leq 6| X > 4] = \frac{Pr[4 < X \leq 6]}{Pr[X > 4]} = \frac{Pr[(4-7)/2 < Z \leq (6-7)/2]}{Pr[Z > (4-7)/2]}
 = \frac{Pr[-1.5 < Z \leq -.5]}{Pr[Z > -1.5]} = (.3085-.0668)/(1-.0668)$$

I'm getting $.259$, but I believe this answer is incorrect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is $a$ known or not? If not, then I don't know where you got the bound $4<X$.

Comment: a is not known.

Comment: Once you find $a$ and $b$ the rest should not be difficult. To find them, prove and use the fact (obvious) that the mean is $\frac{a+b}{2}$ and that the variance is $\frac{(b-a+1)^2-1}{12}$. That takes some work. Perhaps it is in your book/notes. From this, or in some other way we find $a=4$, $b=10$

Answer (score 3):

The *first* thing you must do is find $a,b$ from the given mean ($7$) and variance ($4$).   Only then can you try to find $\mathsf P(a\leq X\leq 6\mid 4\leq X\leq b)$

The mean and variance of a uniform discrete distribution, $X\sim\mathcal U\{a..b\}$ are:
$$\mathsf E(X) = \frac{a+b}{2} = 7\\\mathsf{Var}(X)= \frac{(a-b+1)^2-1}{12} = 4$$